# Output exception message in Flask-Restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

In Flask-Restful it is possible to define a specific static message when some particular exception is raised:

```
errors = {
           'SomeException': {
            'message': 'Some custom error message',
            'status': 500,
        }
}

api_bp = Blueprint('my_bp', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp, errors=errors)
```

The problem is that my `SomeException` contains data which I want to return in a response as well. Is there a way? With a pure Flask I could just create a function with all needed logic and decorate it with the `errorhandler` decorator.

But how do I do that with Flask-Restful?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the error messages in the abort() call.

```
if something_is_wrong:
    custom_message = 'Here is my custom error'
    abort(400, message='There is an error: ' + custom_message)
```

This will abort the script and return an HTTP status 400 response with this in the body:

```
{"message":"There is an error: Here is my custom error"}
```

Comment: This is very incovinient. I should surround each method with try/except block and abort in case of error with a correct message. This is very noisy.

Comment: True, though you can skip using abort() and just use pure Flask for that. Flask-Restful is just some added functionality on top of Flask, which some find helpful and others don't.